# event.getSource().get() not working after Summer 16 release

Tags: lightning

Trying to read currently clicked source's title using `event.getSource().get("{!v.title}")` and set it to the Event attribute. But it is showing me below error.

> Action failed:
>   c$AssignedAssessmentListItemToPatient$controller$fireatq [SyntaxError:
>   Invalid key {!v.title}] Failing descriptor:
>   {c$AssignedAssessmentListItemToPatient$controller$fireatq}. Please try
>   again.

It was working fine before Summer 16 release.
Please find below code:

```
fireatq : function(component, event, helper) {
   var action = $A.get("e.c:ATQEvent");
   action.setParams({"AssId" : event.getSource().get("{!v.title}")}
   action.fire();
}
```

Comment: try `get("v.title")` instead of `get("{!v.title}")`

Answer (score 1):

Since Lightning Components Bundle version 39 or above, this seems to have been stable now.

If you have an event like `onclick` on an HTML tag like `<div>`, you can use `event.currentTarget`.

But if the event is for a Lightning Component tag like `<lightning:button>`, you need to use `event.getSource()`.

This has been well documented in the [Event Handling section of Lightning Components Developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_events.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can assign entire objects and then get them via event.currentTarget. Not sure how long is it going to work for, but works with LS in v40:

```
<lightning:button
    label="View"
    name="view"
    onclick="{!c.toggleView}"
    variant="{! if(v.state.screen == 'view', 'brand', 'neutral') }"/>


toggleView: function(cmp, event, helper) {
  const view = event.currentTarget.name
  cmp.set('v.state.screen', view)
}
```

OR

```
<lightning:button
    label="Foo"
    name="{!v.someObject}"
    onclick="{!c.baz}"/>

baz: function(cmp, event, helper) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.name)
}
```

Unsure if this answers your question, but it's a nice and a useful pattern to use.

Comment: I think something has quietly changed and... it doesn't seem to work anymore.